# Adding Sections Completion Percentages of a Whole

Tags: percentages

If a project is divided into two parts and part one is 50% complete and part two is 25% complete, what percentage of the project is completed?

```
Number of Parts: 2
Part 1: 50%
Part 2: 25%
```

> (Part 1 + Part 2) / Parts = Project Completion Percentage

```
(50 + 25) = 75
75 / 2 = 38 (rounded)
```

Is this logic correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Does each part carry equal weight? For example, suppose the first part takes $100$ hours and the second part takes an hour. Then we have completed $50$ hours and $15$ minutes of a $101$ hour project so we are $\frac{50.25}{101}$ complete which is just under $50\%$ complete.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes, the completion percentage of each part is calculated individually. I'm not trying to calculate the remaining effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic is correct but upto the assumption that the project initally take is divided in equal parts. When the project is not divided in equal parts the correct method will be as follows

Let the method be divided in x% and (100-x)%
The total completion in this case will be 50% of x% + 25% of (100-x)%

Your method works as x = 100 - x = 50, This logic can also be extended to more partitions of projects and the answer will still be obtained in a similar fashion.

***Total Percentages/Total Equipartions***

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume total work is 100.

Then work is divided in two parts x and 100-x.

${x}$ work is completed 50% = $\dfrac{x}{2}$

(${100 - x}$) work is completed 25% = $\dfrac{100-x}{4}$

Therefore total work done is

$$\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{100-x}{4}$$
$$\dfrac{x+100}{4}$$

Example
${x}$ = 50
Total work completed is $$\dfrac{100+50}{4} = 37.5$$